# Is it possible to detect if page was opened via navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to detect if page was opened via my navigation bar?
I have script for my school project which opens up navigation bar. It looks like this:

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.width = "14%";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "14%";
  }
  

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.width = "0%";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0%";
  }
```

It opens up my navbar and I choose which website I want to go to.
This is navbar part of html.

```
<script src="navbar.js"></script>
    <div id="navbar" class="sidebar">
        <a href="index.html" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <a class="active" href="index.html">Kvantový počítač</a>
        <a href="Double slit experiment.html" onclick="scriptDec()">Youngov experiment</a>
        <a href="Qbit.html">Qubit a superpozícia</a>
    </div>
```

It takes me to the website and closes navbar. I would like the navbar to be opened. Is there a possibility to let it open

Comment: Save whether the navbar was opened or closed in `localStorage` and when the page loads check if the navbar was opened and re-open it if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, for example if you are using Google Analytics to track your website trafic if you use ?source=navbar in your URL Google Analytics can see that the request is created from a Navbar interaction.

You can do that:

```
<div id="navbar" class="sidebar">
    <a href="index.html?source=navbar" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a class="active" href="index.html?source=navbar">Kvantový počítač</a>
    <a href="Double slit experiment.html?source=navbar" onclick="scriptDec()">Youngov experiment</a>
    <a href="Qbit.html?source=navbar">Qubit a superpozícia</a>
</div>
```

So, you only need check it in your backend server or via JS.

Answer (score 1):

> Clicking on a link closes the navbar before taking the user to another website. Is there a way to leave the navbar open?

Ans: One thing you can do, is set `target = "_blank"`. This will open the link in a new tab or window, leaving your navbar untouched in its own tab or window. Like this...

`<a href = "https://www.google.com" target = "_blank"> google </a>`

> Is it possible to detect if a website was openned via my navbar?

Ans: Yes! There are several ways to do it.

Soln1: Use "cookies". Cookies are used by web pages to store and retrieve information on the user's computer. The cookies are not destroyed when user leaves your site. So when the user comes back to your site, you can check if the user's computer already has a cookie that was previously set by your site.

Soln2: Use `window.localStorage` in a similar way. But here you have to manually delete the info using `window.clear()` in the end. After clicking a link, whenever the user comes back to your website, he/she can check which link he/she clicked on. Try it out!

```html
<p id="pp"></p>
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="addSiteToCookie('www.google.com')">
      www.google.com
    </a>
<br/>
<a href="http://www.geeksforgeeks.org" onclick="addSiteToCookie('www.geeksforgeeks.org')">
      www.geeksforgeeks.org
    </a>
<br/>
<button onclick="localStorage.clear()"> Clear </button>
<button onclick="display_visited()"> Display visited URLs</button>
<script defer>

  /* THE FUNCTION THAT YOU NEED */
  function addSiteToCookie(site_name) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("sites_visited") == null) {
      localStorage.setItem("sites_visited", site_name);
    } else {
      var prev_visits = localStorage.getItem("sites_visited");
      prev_visits = prev_visits + ";" + site_name;
      localStorage.setItem("sites_visited", prev_visits);
    }
  }

  function display_visited() {
    document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML =
      "sites_visited = " + localStorage.getItem("sites_visited");
  }
</script>
```